# Place twilio call on hold

Tags: javascript, php, twilio, twilio-php

I have an existing softphone dialer using the php & javascript sdk's. It accepts & makes calls without problems.

I'm trying to add 'hold' functionality to the dialer, however every time i try to update the call's url:

```
$call = $client
  ->calls($_REQUEST['callSid'])
  ->update(['url' => '/hold-queue]);
```

and `/hold-queue`

```
<Response>
  <Enqueue waitUrl="/hold-music">test</Enqueue>
</Response>
```

The external phone is disconnected and the soft phone is placed into the queue instead.

Even if I dont try the `<Enqueue>` and use a simple `<Play>` tag I still have this problem.

I need to apply the twiml to the context of the external caller, not the soft phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you place an outbound call using softphone ( Twilio Client implementation ) , there are two legs of the call

- An inbound API into Twilio
- Outbound  to the destination number

The second is the call SID associated to the external dial and the calls sid for this is stored as "Child Call SID" . I suspect you are using "CallSID" to modify the call and hence your experience. Can you check if that is the case and use "Child Call SID" . Let me know if it helps.